# Как вывести составную строку на Python?

Tags: python

Как на Python запросить от пользователя 2 слова, чтобы затем вывести строку "Обычный текст `слово1` обычный текст `слово2`"? `слово1` и `слово2` — это запрошенные ранее строки.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте это:

```
a = input()
b = input()

print('обычный текст' + a + 'обычный текст' + b)
```

или

```
a = input()
b = input()

print('обычный текст {} обычный текст {}'.format(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
a = input ()

b = input ()

print ('обычный текст', a)

print ('обычный текст', в)
```

А вообще из вопроса не понятно как нужно вывести текст на одной строке или на разных, слитно или раздельно и как юзер вводит слова вместе или раздельно  и т п. Формулируйте точнее тогда получите более релевантный ответ.